# How to display an image(as error) instead of error message

Tags: reactjs, onerror

```
const FALLBACK_IMAGE = "https://devprojectupload.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/32490.png";


const ModelComponent = (props) => {

  const [height, setHeight] = useState(window.innerHeight);
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);
  
  //API data 
  const [modelData, setModelData] = useState([]);
  
  //Error
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState("");
```

useEffect(() => {
axios.
get("https://51fgc922b7.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/dev/productpreview")
.then((res) => {
console.log(res.data.data)
setModelData(res.data.data[0])
})
.catch((error)=>
setIsError(()=>{
, error
})
)
}, []);

Comment: What about creating new Error Component and redirect error to that component routes,Have you tried this

Comment: Format your code correctly, please

Answer (score 0):

Currently you're not returning anything in your `setIsError` function. You can return the error you receive from the catch or just set it to `true`

```js
setIsError(()=>{
  return error;
  // return true;
})
```

In the return of your component you could do something like this, where you check if there is an error and if there is you display your `img`

```js
return (
  ...
  {isError && <img src={FALLBACK_IMAGE} alt="error"/>}
  ...
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It helped me to resolve the issue.